# Can Thamsanqa JantjieIs (from Mandela's funeral) actually act as a sign language interpreter?

Tags: nelson-mandela

The [Telegraph reported](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/africaandindianocean/southafrica/10510455/Nelson-Mandela-memorial-interpreter-was-a-fake.html) that the (then unidentified) man who attempted to provide sign translations at Nelson Mandela's funeral was a fake:

> Mr Buxton said he was purely making “childish hand gestures and clapping, it was as if he had never learn a word of sign language in his life”.

He was later identified as Thamsanqa Jantjie, and he was confirmed as accredited by the [South African government](https://twitter.com/SAgovnews/statuses/411095362523250689), but claimed he had a schizophrenic episode at the time. (For example [NBN News](http://worldnews.nbcnews.com/_news/2013/12/13/21887836-mandela-service-sign-language-interpreter-failed-in-2012-with-self-invented-gestures))

Has Thamsanqa Jantjie demonstrated he can translate sign language before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can find no press reports of Thamsanqa Jantjie performing satisfactorily as a sign-language interpreter.

There are reports that suggest his incomprehensible performance was not an isolated incident.

---

> US broadcaster CBS News’ archival footage of a press conference on June 24 shows Jantjies did the same thing during an international press briefing given by President Jacob Zuma.
>
> It was two weeks after Mandela was hospitalised and shortly before US President Barack Obama arrived in South Africa.
>
> I asked Zuma: “Nelson Mandela is critically ill at a time when US President Barack Obama is due to visit South Africa. Should he cancel his trip?”
>
> Expert sign language interpreter Pholoho Selebano revealed he interpreted the question as: “Toilet! Toilet! Union! Forehead!”
>
> He said he saw “angels” during Mandela’s memorial. I wonder what he saw six months before?
>
> – Debora Patta

reported by [City Press](http://www.citypress.co.za/news/newsmaker-thamsanqa-jantjie-con-crazy-criminal-ballsy) a South African Sunday newspaper.

---

> The Deaf Federation of South Africa said on Wednesday that it had submitted a formal complaint to the ANC about Jantjie’s interpretation after an event in 2012.

[NBC News](http://worldnews.nbcnews.com/_news/2013/12/12/21873839-violent-sign-language-interpreters-access-to-obama-triggers-investigation)

---

There are several sign-languages used in South Africa, but the one most likely to be used at official events may be [South African Sign Language](http://www.education.gov.za/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=ZlJsOf4xcTY%3D&tabid=1011&mid=2687) (SASL), which probably has more in common with [British Sign Language](http://www.britishsignlanguage.com/) (BSL) than with American Sign Language (ASL). This *might* partly explain why some ASL experts are so baffled by what they saw. It doesn't explain why many South Africans believe Thamsanqa Jantjie's sign language is incomprehensible or nonsense.

Comment: How in the earth someone as incompetent as that guy got the job? Affirmative action?